# jQuery .hover(function{}) only on actual hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm familiar with jQuery but i have one little setback. I would like the function to be called only when i just hover the element, and not when im already hovering it and i slightly move the mouse.

I simply want the function to be called only if i'm entering the area of the element from outside of it.

I hope this makes sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: what did you tried? can we see your attempts on a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Works perfectly with `.hover`: http://jsfiddle.net/3WZPx/

Answer (score 1):

The [`hover` method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) binds an event handler for [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and one for [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), so it won't trigger any event whenever the mouse is moved within the element.

It's the [`mousemove`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event that is used for that. Perhaps you are binding that also somewhere?

If you only want to handle the event when the mouse enters, and not when it leaves, used the `mouseenter` method instead of `hover`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need mouseenter and not the whole hover event

```
$(div).mouseenter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes hover will bind a mouseenter and a mouseleave to your selector:

try:

```
$(div).mouseenter(function(){
      //Do whatever you want to do on your mouse enter.
)}
```